# How to make two buttons separate in a div?

Tags: css

This is my code for the two buttons:

HTML:

```
<div clas="buttons">
<a class="btn1" href="#">Ture</a>
<a class="btn2" href="#">False</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn1 {
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-left: 150px;
}
.btn2 {
margin-right: 150px;
}
```

However, "the margin-bottom:30px" attribute simply doesn't work. It failed to position the button vertically. Even more weirdly, the "margin-right: 150px;" attribute doesn't work for my btn2, and the two buttons are still adjoin to each other. BTW, my div is large enough to have the two buttons positioned seperately.

Answer (score 5):

Margins should only be applied on block level elements. They will give unexpected results if you apply them on inlines, wich the `<a>` are by default: You could set padding in stead of margin. And indeed reverse them as @Mitz correctly suggested. The more correct way, but perhaps more difficult for beginners, would be to convert the `<a>` to block and float them left. Personally my css would look something like this:

```
.buttons {
 padding: 30px 150px;
 overflow: hidden; /* for clearfix */
}
.btn1, .btn2 {
  display: block;
}
.btn1 {
  float: left;
}
.btn2 {
  float: right;
}
```

That is just how I interpret your code and think what you might want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This is because naturally `<a>` is an inline element. You need to apply `display: block;` to it if you want to apply margins.

The two buttons will be one above the other afterwards. If you still want them to appear next to each other then you should `float: left;` them. And don't forget to apply some kind of `.clearfix`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use margin-top and margin-left, instead of margin-bottom and margin-right...

you can use first button's height to push the other button down, like this

```
.btn1 { height:200px; }
```

and if you are using margins you should always define some height and width, like

```
.btn1 { height:20px; width:100px; }
.btn2 { height:20px; width:100px; padding-top:150px; }
```

update: 
about the float comment-
float will get the two buttons sit side by side horizontally,
i think he wanted them aligned vertically

Comment: Why should you always define width/height when applying margins? I think you are mistaken. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can try float:left; for buttons.